# How to make an Array equal another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables, variable-assignment

I am having trouble making an array equal another array in c.
in the main method it will not let me assign inputInt1 to the returned value of converTwosComp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int validChecker(char *input_StringIn);
int* convertTwosComp(char *inputStringIn, int *inputIntIn);
int main(void) {
    char inputString1[11];
    char inputString2[11];
    int inputInt1[11];
    int inputInt2[11];

    printf(" is ");
    inputInt1 = convertTwosComp(inputString1, inputInt1);
    for(i = 0; inputString1[i]; i++){
        printf("%d", inputInt1[i]);
    }


    int * convertTwosComp(char *inputStringIn, int *inputIntIn){
    int digit;
    int i;

    if((inputStringIn[0] == '+') ||(inputStringIn[0]) == '0'){
        inputStringIn[0] = 0;
    }
    if(inputStringIn[0] == '-'){
        inputStringIn[0] = 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; inputStringIn[i]; i++){
        digit = inputStringIn[i] - '0';
        inputStringIn[i] = digit;
    }

    for(i = 0; inputIntIn[i]; i++){
        if(inputIntIn[i] == 0){
            inputIntIn[i] = 1;
        }
        if(inputIntIn[i] == 1){
            inputIntIn[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return inputIntIn;



}
```

in the main method it will not let me assign inputInt1 to the returned value of converTwosComp.

Comment: **char inputString1[11];** vs **int* convertTwosComp(char *inputStringIn, int *inputIntIn);**  do you see the difference ?

Comment: honestly I'm a bit lost but I think you are saying that I'm returning a pointer and not an array...maybe?

Comment: `void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);`

Comment: @WeatherVane any chance you could elaborate I'm not familiar with that function.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx In this case `count` is the number of **bytes** to be copied, nothing to do with data size as used with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: ... although I'm not sure you really mean one array to be **equal** to another if they are of different types.

Comment: C does not permit assigning to whole arrays.  You can assign to variables of pointer type (which sometimes point to arrays), or you can can copy *elements* from one array to another.  As it is currently declared in your code, however, variable `inputInt1` is not itself a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: void *memcpy(*inputInt1,*convertTwosComp(inputString1, inputInt1), 10);

would this be the way to use that function. @WeatherVane

Comment: On the other hand, you might not need to assign at all.  If, as in your code, you pass an array as a function argument, then the called function can modify the array (elements) directly.  You might not need anything more.

Comment: Having looked at your code a bit closer, and its different data types, it's not really clear what array you want to "equal" which other. And no, that's not the way to use that function. The answer from @Michi shows the straight forward way to copy one array to another array (provided the target has enough elements).

Comment: You're not trying to assign one array to another; you're trying to assign a pointer to an array.

Comment: C does not support **methods**, but only **functions**

Answer (score 1):

This is what you probably need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char array1[] = "Michi";
    size_t len = strlen(array1);
    char *array2 = malloc(len+1);

    memcpy(array2, array1, len+1);

    printf("Array2 = %s\n",array2);
    free(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Array2 = Michi

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a for loop to copy a string, in case you do not want to use memcpy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char one[30];
    char two[30];
    while(fgets(one,sizeof(one),stdin))
    {
        int len = strlen(one);
        for(int i = 0; i < (len + 1); i++)
        {
            two[i] = one[i];
        }
        printf("%s", two);
        break;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```